# How to undo always openwith option

Tags: open-with

I am not able to open my ipynb file as I by mistake clicked on alway open with option of acrobat which is converting my ipynb file to acrobat as soon as i download it. please guide how to undo this action of mine

Comment: If you are on Windows 10, you can change it using Settings -> Default Apps, then click "Choose default apps by file type", see instructions [here](http://woshub.com/managing-default-file-associations-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.